# reading and printing a .csv file like a 2D matrix with both integer and float values in c

Tags: c, file, csv

Reading a file in c with .csv as extension. The file consisting of both integer and float type data values. Is there any way to read the csv file. Any help is appreciated.

The data is as follows:

```
Application_No. Actual_Effort (in PM)   No of Processes No of Tasks No of partnerLinks  Task Variables  Element Variables   Event Variables Script  Developer's Skills  Developer's Confidence  TPSS    TS  TCC
1   918.28  1   3   5   33  7   2   3   3.5 1   8   135 143
2   8891.513    3   9   3   100 15  6   12  3   1   36  1197    1233
3   22479.261   5   15  23  125 25  10  20  3   1   190 2700    2890
4   2961.131    2   4   9   70  13  4   17  2   0   72  416 488
5   19650.198   7   14  19  130 28  12  5   2.5 0   231 2450    2681
6   377.75  1   2   4   22  8   2   2   3   1   6   68  74
7   2671.93 1   5   12  55  12  6   4   2   0   17  385 402
8   966.15  3   3   6   31  8   5   7   2.5 0   27  153 180
9   3765.81 2   6   17  73  14  2   3   3.5 1   46  552 590
10  7467.11 4   8   21  87  19  13  1   2   0   116 960 1076
```

Comment: The dataset is in .csv format. Sorry exactly i couldn't represent the dataset. is there any possible way just to read the file in c? The dataset containing 14 columns and 11 rows. Alphanumeric data are there. Also Numeric data are the combination of int and float type

Comment: fscanf's "%lf" (double) for both int and float.